# Ошибка: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Бьюсь второй день с этим. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Entity class:**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book
{
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;
  private String title;

  public Book() {
  }

  public Book(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

**main:**

```
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    public class main
    {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        Book book = new Book("test");
        et.begin();
        em.persist(book);
        et.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
        }
    }
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.pushkartech</groupId>
  <artifactId>JPAStudy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>


</project>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <!-- Define persistence unit -->
  <persistence-unit name="test">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Book</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studyjpa"/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>-->

      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studyjpa"/>
      <property name="ibernate.connection.name" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>



    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**вывод консоли:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=62757:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Projects\JPAStudy\target\classes;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.12\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.6.0\protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.6.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.1-GA\javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.17\byte-buddy-1.8.17.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\javaee-api-7.0-1.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" main
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:01 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: test
    ...]
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:01 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:01 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studyjpa]
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****}
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sat Oct 06 18:29:02 EEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
жовт. 06, 2018 6:29:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at main.main(main.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 37 more
```

Как это можно разрешить? `persistence.xml` лежит в `resources/META-INF`.

---

добавил `hibernate.dialect` и вышли новые эксепшены.

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=62255:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Projects\JPAStudy\target\classes;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.12\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.6.0\protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.6.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.1-GA\javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.17\byte-buddy-1.8.17.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Anton\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\javaee-api-7.0-1.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Program\TomEE+\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" main
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:44 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: test
    ...]
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studyjpa]
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****}
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sat Oct 06 19:13:45 EEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
жовт. 06, 2018 7:13:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at main.main(main.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что вы не указали свойство диалекта в Hibernate. Добавьте свойство в конфигурацию

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Вы можете почитать больше про [диалекты Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect) в руководстве.

Comment: Добавил. Вышли новые эксепшены. Как с ними быть?

Comment: @Антон он не может подключиться к бд ибо доступ запрещен. Логин, пароль возможно не верны или ограничения в БД есть.